# Line spacing in TikZ multiline nodes inside tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-spacing

I'm trying to typeset some multiline `TikZ` nodes inside a `tabular` environment. Somehow, the space between lines gets considerably shortened.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [align=center] {
    \underline{$(\alpha \land \beta)$}\\
    $\alpha$\\
    $\beta$
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [align=center] {
    \underline{$(\alpha \land \beta)$}\\
        $\alpha$\\
        $\beta$
        };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Can someone explain what is happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: A manual solution: Add `\strut` to every line.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Jerzy. For future reference, it's better to provide small, complete `.tex` documents rather than just snippets. Otherwise I have to type out `\documentclass{article}`, `\end{document}` etc., and work out which packages you've used, all before I can reproduce your situation on my machine and start thinking about a situation.

Comment: Qrrbrbirlbel, that didn't seem to work. Should I add `\strut` to the first or to the last cell in the row?

Comment: John, I'll remember that next time! Already edited the question to include document header, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the `tikzpicture` in a box, outside of the `tabular`, and then use it once you're inside the `tabular`. What I mean is...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\john
\sbox\john{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [align=center] {
    \underline{$(\alpha \land \beta)$}\\
    $\alpha$\\
    $\beta$
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tabular}{c}
\usebox\john
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

By the way, if you're drawing proof trees, you might find the **[`bussproofs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bussproofs)** or **[`mathpartir`](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/)** packages helpful.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'm just drawing basic tableaux-style proofs in propositional logic. So far, Tikz trees are enough for my needs, but I'll have a look at those packages!

Comment: @JerzyBrzozowski Another package for proof trees is [`prooftrees`](http://ctan.org/pkg/prooftrees).